# PDO_mysql not working with doctrine2 and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine

For some reason, why I attempt to connect to my local mysql database using doctrine. I get the following error:

```
Could not create database for connection named `new_db` could not find driver
```

My PHPinfo file tells me that pdo_mysql is running, is version 5.5.38 and is supposedly located here: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock (however I can't find mysql.sock in that directory).

The php.ini file according to the php info file is located here:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf
Loaded Configuration File   /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

My command line (which has been configured to point to the same version of PHP as mamp (in theory) states that it is using the following php.ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini
```

I'm unsure why phpinfo has a different 'Loaded configuration file' entry and I wonder if this is the problem, however I'm unsure how to change that. Interestingly though both files state that pdo_mysql should be loaded.

Annoyingly, in spite of all php.ini files I can find stating that pdo_mysql is loaded when I type `php -m | grep -G PDO -i` I only see:

```
PDO
pdo_sqlite
```

I'm at a loss as to why pdo_mysql isn't loading as it really seems that it should be.

I am running MAMP Pro on Mac OSx Yosemite.

Edit: As requested, here is the connection string which is auto-generated by symfony:

```
{ parameters: { database_driver: pdo_mysql, database_host: 127.0.0.1, database_port: 3306, database_name: new_db, database_user: dbuser, database_password: dbpass, mailer_transport: smtp, mailer_host: 127.0.0.1, mailer_user: null, mailer_password: null, locale: en, secret: thisisnotmysecret, debug_toolbar: true, debug_redirects: false, use_assetic_controller: true, database_path: null } }
```

Update: After attempting to connect without the framework I got the following error:

> [20-Oct-2014 17:15:44 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_mysql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_mysql.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

This is irritating as the folder it SHOULD point to is "no-debug-non-zts-20131226" and not "no-debug-non-zts-20121212" Does anyone know how to update this path?

Comment: "for a connection named 'new_db'". Sounds like your PDO connection string is incorrect. Show that code instead.

Comment: That seems right; is there any setting on Doctrines side to load the PDO? Try to create a basic php script that uses PDO without the framework or doctrine to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Mamp pro's default php.ini file was wrong. It thought that the extension dir should be:

extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/"

When it should actually have been:

extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/"

I updated the file and now it works like a charm :)